# Adding order details in woocommerce all booking dashboard

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

[image]

Is there any way to added wocommerce order details in this tab? I saw hooks available for woocommerce order page but not for woocommercce booking page.

Answer (score 0):

Booking is custom post type and not the default woo-commerce set up, you need to modify your post type's screen hook accordingly and fetch order details via particular id to show it, it can not be done directly from woo-commerce or it's hooks.

Comment: Then how can i modify my post type?

Comment: You need to use manage_post_type_posts_columns hook : https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_post_type_posts_columns/